# Fullscreen Page slide with navigation

Tags: html, css, fullscreen, slide

I'm quite new to this, so many of you might find my question stupid but I really need help!!

Ok, so what I am trying to achieve is:

I want 6 Fullscreen Pages with image and content to smoothly scroll horizontally when clicked on "<" ">" buttons AND there will also be bullets for each page at the bottom of the website.

How do I set this on a HTML & CSS? I know it might be pretty easy, but honestly with my skills, I can't seem to find the way!

I want the exact same effect as http://nicinabox.com/superslides/#1

Comment: Err...I don't think you can do this with purely HTML/CSS. You HAVE to use JavaScript :) BTW, why not use the jQuery plug-in that you've linked to?

Comment: Here is an answer that describes a similar technique of [horizontal fullscreen page sliding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24414642/responsive-horizontal-page-sliding-navigation/24465646#24465646)

Answer (score 0):

Check http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/

you can put the swiper's css width:100 height:100 top:0 and each swiper left:0 , 100%,200%,300%...

It has a lot of demos you can use. It also work pretty fine on touch devices.